# External API calls not working in shared hosting but working perfectly on local host

Tags: node.js, api, axios, request, shared-hosting

I have a node js application that uses external APIs from a different backend. I made some requests using vanilla js and some from within my node js/express. They all work fine in my localhost until I deployed to production on cpanel.

Here is my code:

```
//ROUTE

router.route('/job-search')
    .get(Controller.getSearch);

//CONTROLLER

const Request  = require('request');

    getSearch: (req, res) => {
        if (req.query.position || req.query.location || req.query.type || req.query.level ||  req.query.sector) {
            const position = req.query.position
            const form = {
                available_post: req.query.position,
                sector_id: req.query.sector,
                city_assignment_id: req.query.location,
                job_type_id: req.query.type,
                function_id: req.query.level  
            };
            
            const type = req.query.type !== undefined  ?  Number(req.query.type) : '';
            const level = req.query.level !== undefined  ? Number(req.query.level) : '';
            const sector = req.query.sector !== undefined  ? Number(req.query.sector) : '';
            const location = req.query.location !== undefined  ? Number(req.query.location) : '';
            const params = 'position='+req.query.position+'&sector='+sector+'&location='+location+'&type='+type+'&level='+level;
           //console.log("params: " + params)
            const page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1;
            
            Request.post({
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                "url": `https://jobatrac.com/api/job_postings/search?page=${page}`,
                "body": JSON.stringify(form)
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                if(error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }
               var results = JSON.parse(body)
                const newIvory = results.data
                const num_next = results.links.next
                const num_prev = results.links.prev
                const count = results.meta.total;
                const fromValue = results.meta.from;
                const toValue = results.meta.to;

                
                if (num_next !== null && num_prev !== null ){
                    var previous = num_prev.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    var next = num_next.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (jobTitle LIKE '%${position}%') ORDER BY posted DESC`, (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, next, previous, params, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }
                else if (num_next !== null && num_prev == null ){
                    var next = num_next.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (jobTitle LIKE '%${position}%') ORDER BY posted DESC`, (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, next, params, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }
                else if (num_prev !== null  && num_next == null ){
                    var previous = num_prev.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (jobTitle LIKE '%${position}%') ORDER BY posted DESC`, (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, previous, params, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE (jobTitle LIKE '%${position}%') ORDER BY posted DESC`, (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    
        }else{
            const page = req.query.page ? Number(req.query.page) : 1;   
            Request.get({
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                "url": `https://jobatrac.com/api/job_postings?page=${page}`,
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                if(error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                var results = JSON.parse(body)
                const newIvory = results.data
                const num_next = results.links.next
                const num_prev = results.links.prev
                const count = results.meta.total;
                const fromValue = results.meta.from;
                const toValue = results.meta.to;
                const allSearch = 1;
                if (num_next !== null && num_prev !== null ){
                    var previous = num_prev.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    var next = num_next.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posted DESC', (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, fromValue, toValue, newIvory, next, previous, allSearch, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }
                else if (num_next !== null && num_prev == null ){
                    var next = num_next.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posted DESC', (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, next, allSearch, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }
                else if (num_prev !== null  && num_next == null ){
                    var previous = num_prev.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posted DESC', (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, newIvory, fromValue, toValue, previous, allSearch, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    })
                }else{
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY posted DESC', (err, jobs) => {
                        if (!err){
                            res.render('default/job-search', {jobs: jobs, fromValue, toValue, newIvory, allSearch, count})
                        }else{
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                }
                
            } 
            )};
    },
```

The requests I made using vanilla js are working fine but the requests using node packages aren't working. The server responds with "incomplete response from server". I have tried axios, and request packages but while they both work on local host, neither works on the server. I would try gotStream and node-fetch but my server has a node -12.22.7.

I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Please show us the exact relevant code that is having problems.  If you can, show us exactly what the external host is so we can try to reproduce issues on our own.  Questions about code here should include the relevant code in the question.  You will get quicker and more accurate and more complete answers if we can see your actual code.  Not words only.  Not pseudo code.  Not abstracted code.  Real code.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the exact code.

Comment: FYI, the request library is deprecated and should not be used for new code.  It's features will not be advancing going forward.  The list of alternatives is [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) - all of which support promises which is how you should be coding asynchronous operations in nodejs these days.

Comment: What is this `connection.query()`?  Are you 100% sure this database is working properly on your cpanel deployment?

Comment: Also `throw err` in a `connection.query()` callback does NOTHING useful as nobody can catch it.  If you get an error there, you need to log the error send an error response to the http request you're  processing, such as `console.log(err);  res.sendStatus(500);`.  It seems likely you have a database error, but don't log that error or handle it properly.  ***When, in doubt go fix ALL your error handling to make sure everything logs and does something useful when it gets an error.***

Comment: I am aware the request library is deprecated but I had the exact same issue using axios. Connection.query fetches data from a local database and I'm positive it is working quite fine.